# How can I change the color of my shell when a specific command is used?

Tags: shell, fish, iterm2

Whenever I use ssh I would like the background of my terminal to change color. The usage of ssh usually signifies that I'm logged into a production environment so care should be taken to not do anything stupid.

Right now I'm using iterm2, but happy to hear if this can be done in a good way for any other shell.

Comment: iterm2 is a terminal emulator, not a shell

Comment: And have you tried anything?

Comment: alternative, you could set the prompt colour (e.g. set background to red for prod boxes); so alias the `ssh` command to set colour and then do the ssh.  Doesn't affect full screen background though ... but the prompt will give some visual indication.

Comment: @DarrenSmith This will not work because after "ssh" the shell that "runs" is the distant one not the local...

Comment: I can recommend you to read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234393/passing-variable-definitions-to-specific-shells-in-ssh and configure the distant shell to use a specific prompt or alike...

Comment: I think I'll be getting somewhere using the code written in this gist: https://gist.github.com/wadey/1140259

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible in any portable fashion because there is no generally recognized escape sequence for changing things like the terminal background color.

Note that the example script you linked to only changes the background color of the current iTerm terminal tab; not the background color of the terminal text area. If, like me most of the time, you only have one tab and have configured iterm not to show tabs when there is only one you won't see that color change. It will also not work if you are doing this inside a `screen` or `tmux` session (you'll need to wrap the sequence in a special tmux "pass through" sequence).

What I recommend is the same thing I do when I do `sudo fish` to run the shell as root. Modify your `fish_prompt` function to detect the special situation and use an alternative prompt. For example, here is the relevant portion of my `fish_prompt` function for making it obvious when I'm root:

```
set -l color_cmd_sep $fish_color_host
if test "$USER" = 'root'
    set color_cmd_sep -b bryellow red
end

echo -ns (set_color $fish_color_host) $now ' ' $__fish_prompt_hostname
echo -ns (set_color $fish_color_cwd) ' ' (prompt_pwd) ' ' (set_color normal)
echo -ns (set_color $fish_color_git) (__fish_vcs_prompt | string trim) (set_color normal)
echo -ns (set_color $color_cmd_sep) '>' (set_color normal) ' '
```

All you need to do is add a similar test for being inside a ssh session; e.g., by testing for the presence of a `SSH_CLIENT` or `SSH_CONNECTION` env var: `if set -q SSH_CLIENT`. If true alter the colors or content of the prompt.

Comment: iTerm's "automatic profile switching", as mentioned by ridiculous_fish's answer, can be used for this but it is obviously limited to just iTerm. It is also an extremely complicated feature of iTerm (which I've been using as my primary shell for more than ten years). I prefer a solution, such as a custom `fish_prompt` function, that works regardless of the terminal type. Especially since anyone likely to care about this scenario is likely to be using `screen` or `tmux` and also likely to, at least occasionally, use a terminal other than iTerm.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in iTerm2 via [Automatic Profile Switching](https://iterm2.com/documentation-automatic-profile-switching.html).